# How to get Arduino to read serial from Python?

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, arduino-uno, pyserial

## Specific problem

I am trying to communicate between a Python script and my Arduino Pro Mini using serial with a USB cable. In Python I can read what the Arduino writes but the Arduino can either not read what the Python writes or it is reading it in a form that I can't process. The most obvious way this manifests itself is when I try to write what the Arduino has just read from Python, to Python. Nothing gets displayed in Python.

My Arduino sketch appears to work just fine when I work with it in the Serial Monitor, i.e. it can read and write so I suspect it is something at the Python end. What's causing this?

## Details

I want to be able test how quickly I can send 64 byte-long pieces of information to my Arduino. To do this I wrote a Python script that could should be able to periodically send various information to my Arduino. I can change the period and thus test what kind of speed I can get.

However, despite the fact that my Arduino sketch works just fine with Serial Monitor, i.e. I can send it information and read information from it, I can't get it to work with Python.

With my Python script I can open the connection and read what the Arduino writes, but for some reason there is a problem with writing from Python. I have tried the following but none of them have worked:

- Using an Uno instead of a Pro Mini.
- Putting a `Serial.println()` statement in my `get_data()` function. Nothing gets printed.
- Sending a string with the format "T(number);" and using `sscanf()` to extract the number. Using an if statement to examine the number and turn an onboard LED on. Did not work.
- Sending a string beginning with "T" and using an if statement to see if it is stored in `raw_data[]`. It isn't.
- Writing the data from Python at different times (i.e. using a longer delay).
- Writing from Python using `device.write(b"mystring")` and `device.write("mystring".encode())`

I'm at a loss for what to try next…

## Python (2.7) code

```py
import serial, time, random, string

device = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-A105YOZX', baudrate = 38400)

initial_time = time.time()
current_time = time.time()

counter = 0
control = 0

while counter < 1000:
    current_time = time.time()
    if current_time - initial_time > 0.1:
        initial_time = current_time
        counter += 1
        device.read()
    if current_time - initial_time > 1 and control == 0:
        device.write(b"Message being sent")
        control = 1
```

## Arduino code

```cpp
#define RAW_LEN 64 //max length of incoming string (buffer size is only 64 bytes)

//variables for incoming data
char raw_data[RAW_LEN];
int raw_data_i = 0; //index

unsigned long my_time;
int control = 0;
int for_print;

int get_data(int i) {
  //fills up raw_data[] with serial data. Clears raw_data if it gets too long
  if (Serial.available()>0) {
    raw_data[i] = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(raw_data[i]);
    //Serial.println(raw_data[i]);
    if (i<RAW_LEN-1){
      i++;
    }
  }
  return i;
}

void clear_data() {
  //clears raw_data and resets raw_data_i
  raw_data_i = 0;
  memset(raw_data,'\0',RAW_LEN-1);
}

//print functions
void raw_print(char data[]) {
  Serial.println("Received data: ");
  //if (raw_data[0] == 'T') {digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);}
  for (int i=0; i< RAW_LEN;i++) {
    Serial.println(data[i]);
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Serial.println("Restart");
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  my_time = millis();
  raw_data_i = get_data(raw_data_i);
  //clear raw_data if it gets full
  if (raw_data_i == RAW_LEN-1) {
    clear_data();
  }

  if (my_time > 5000 && control == 0) {
    Serial.println("Here");
    raw_print(raw_data);
    control = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: `raw_data` is a char vector, so when reading from Serial cast it to a char:  `raw_data[i] = (char)Serial.read()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it and it still works with Serial Monitor but not with Python…

Comment: What is `device.read()` supposed to do?

Comment: I'm printing the data the Arduino has received back to the serial port, so the `device.read()` should read it and print it. I made a mistake in the code I copied across – it should be `print device.read()`.

Comment: flagged for moving to arduino specific community.  tks, tg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the Python code. In `while` loop the first `if` statement is `True` after 0.1s, and then executes 9 more times before the second `if` statement is `True`.

The problem with this is that `device.read()` just hangs if it does not receive a character. Because I wasn't sending enough characters from the Arduino the Python code paused at the `device.read()` and never got to the second `if` statement.

An annoying mistake that took a while to figure out, hopefully this question and answer will save someone else a lot of debugging time.